# Python using typing.Union from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, pydantic

I have been trying to get Pydantic to understand that a field is supposed to be one of (Union) of a list that is created in runtime. For example:

```
#In reality this is created automatically
#The classes below are also pydantic classes
prop_types = (MyPropOne, MyPropTwo, MyPropThree)

#...

from typing import Union
from pydantic import BaseModel
from .my_file import prop_types

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    my_prop: Union[prop_types]
```

The error I get is:

> RuntimeError: error checking inheritance of (<class
> 'api.models.cellengineer.cniFeasibility.RevisionAnswersCniFeasibility'>,)
> (type: tuple)

Any idea how to solve this? Each `my_prop` inner model has different fields so I see no other way

Comment: try  Union[*prop_types] this might work